# .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages Conditional Connections String based on Dev or Prod Enviroment

Tags: .net-core, connection-string, razor-pages

I have done this in .NET Web Forms for years:

```
  Dim conn As New SqlConnection(f1.fUseThisConnection(Server.MachineName))

Public Function fUseThisConnection(ByVal strThisMachine As String) As String

    If strThisMachine = "T61" Then
        fUseThisConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DevHome")
    Else
        fUseThisConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Production")
    End If

End Function
```

And the AppSettings are in Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Production" value="server=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;database=xxx;pooling=false" />
    <add key="DevHome" value="server=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;database=xxx;pooling=false" />
```

But I have yet to search and find anything so simple for my C# Razor Pages. Anything from Microsoft howto's just boggles my mind.

Here is my appSetting.json in my Razor Pages project:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {

    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Txx\\SQLxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True",
    "Production": "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
  },
```

And here is where I reference the connections string--which is hardcoded--but I am hoping there is a way to do an "If" statement: "If environment= whatever, then get this connection string".

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
         options => { options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Txxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True"); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the [configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), I suppose you are using Asp Net Core, and you are adding Mvc in your startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseMvc();
    ...
}
```

By default, it will try to load 2 configurations files, `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{Environment}.json`, the latest overrides the contents from the final configuration, and also by default, core already has two environments, `development` and `production`, all depends in which profile you are using (in visual studio by default will be development).

So, your config file could be renamed to `appsettings.json`, then you declare your connection strings for production, and create a file `appsettings.Development.json` were you can override the connection with the development connection string.

You can also load more files o change the default ones by using something like this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            config.AddInMemoryCollection(arrayDict);
            config.AddJsonFile("json_array.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
            config.AddJsonFile("starship.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
            config.AddXmlFile("tvshow.xml", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
            config.AddEFConfiguration(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDb"));
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

If you want the environment variable

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ")
```

**But please, consider being more secure**

For sensible data something more secure could be to configure your connection string as environment variable in your server, this way it can be removed from your code and keep more private.

This and other solution using a secret manager can be found in the [secrets documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows).

### Edit

> Otherwise, it defaults to the "appSettings.json" file (this would be
>   in production)

No, it will not load one or another, first it will load appsettings.json, this is always, no matter what Environment you have.

Then, after it loads `appsettings.json` it will try to load `appsettings.{Environment}.json` and it will add the keys that were not there before, and it will override an old key if exists.

If you have in appSettings

```
{
  "SomeConfigJustInAppSettings": "some value",
  "ThisWillBeOverride": "some value"
}
```

And your appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "SomeConfigJustInDev": "some other value",
  "ThisWillBeOverride": "some other value"
}
```

Your config in dev would ended up being:

```
{
  "SomeConfigJustInAppSettings": "some value",
  "SomeConfigJustInDev": "some other value",
  "ThisWillBeOverride": "some other value"
}
```

> what determines what "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" holds?

Is an [environmental variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), is set in the Operative System. Also, for development Visual studio has the capacity to preload some variables for when you are developing your app, just check your `launchSettings.json`, example:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50051"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```

Specially this part

```
"environmentVariables": {
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
},
```

> It would be nice to just find what the server name is and use that.
>   Because I would only check for my dev box servername, everything else
>   would mean production

Right now it is even more simple, if the variable does not exist, it just loads the appsettings which could contain you prod settings. When you are developing, visual studio (or VS code, or Rider), are already adding the variable with the value `Development`, so all you need to do is to add the file `appsettings.Development.json`.

Hell, you can even just create a new project, the default project layout already creates this two files for you!

[image: Default project created with Visual Studio]

Comment: Ok, the Environment check answers my question. But the appSettings.Development.json sounds great. In other words, if in Dev environment, the ".Development." json file is used. Otherwise, it defaults to the "appSettings.json" file (this would be in production).
Also, what determines what "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" holds? When I publish and upload? It would be nice to just find what the server name is and use that. Because I would only check for my dev box servername, everything else would mean production.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: i already have those appSettings.json files. They came with the .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages I started. I am still confused. Lots of info, no simple use of it. Maybe I'm brain damaged.

Comment: Ok, it gets correct "DefaultConnection" from appsetting.Development.json even though I have "DefaultConnection" set to Production database in appsettings.json. This is desired. Now, when I go to publish my web application, I will just not include the appsettings.Development.json. All is find and dandy except: I cannot use ---var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]; --- in my --public class MyDbContext : DbContext -- OnConfiguring section.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178017/i-cannot-retrieve-connection-string-in-dbcontext-class-in-net-core-2-2-razor-pa

Comment: I got the dynamic connectionstring working with this question I posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178017/i-cannot-retrieve-connection-string-in-dbcontext-class-in-net-core-2-2-razor-pa

I am accepting your answer because your explanation of appSettings.json and how appSettings.Development.json overwrites any similar names made it real easy to publish to production. I just don't include the appSettings.Develpment.json when uploading to production server.

Comment: Thanks, you could also safely leave appSettings.Develpment.json in your build, as long as you do not have the environmental variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" seted to development, it should not load the file anyway.

Comment: Well, I left it in, but it also made a appSettings.Production.json file too. I uploaded them all but got an error that it didn't show because somehow the Environment got set to Production. In order to see the error I have to set my Production environment to Development with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setting, but I don't know how to do this on the remote server. I don't see the launchSettings.json anywhere on the server.

Comment: Then make sure you are adding and copying the file, or check the properties of the file (right click, properties) and set the option "Copy to output directory" as "Copy if newer"

Comment: Thanks @rekiem87!