# I cannot retrieve connection string in DbContext class in .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string, razor-pages

**In Startup.cs Configure Services this works:**

```
var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                 options => { options.UseSqlServer(connection); });
```

**In my MyDbContext.cs class this doesn't work:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

using OESAC.Models;

namespace OESAC.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sponsors> Sponsors{ get; set; }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

           var connection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

            ;
        }


    }
}
```

I can hardcode the connection string but I want it to dynamically change based on my appSettings.Development.json and appSettngs.json (production). I can't believe the time I've spent trying to figure this out. It has cost me way over what I am being paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `IConfiguration` in constructor to have an access to configuration.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)       
    {
       _configuration = configuration
    }

    public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sponsors> Sponsors{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

       var connection = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);            
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow. I was way off on setting up MyDbContext. I'm just not a rocket scientist. Your suggestion in Startup.cs also worked and now I have only one place to call connection string. It is interesting to note that code always looks in appSettings.json first, and appSettings.[Enviroment].json second. Second appsettings will overwrite a name in 1st appsettings. So by placing "DefaultConnection": in both files, and point one at Dev and one at Prod, the appsettings.Development.json will work in dev environment and when publishing it is left out so production "DefaultConnection" gets used.

Comment: @JustJohn: You shouldn't store sensitive information like connection strings in appsettings, since its easy to accidentally commit and the other non-sensitive values needs to be commited (for when you deploy you application). You should use [user secrets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#secret-manager) instead for development and environment variables (docker) or stuff like [azure key-value configuration provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for azure

Comment: @Tseng: Thanks, good idea. Right now the app is in primitive Beta mode and I just wanted to get it working so clients could see it. The data is dummy data. I figure I'll build the house before I put an alarm system or guard dog in the yard.

Comment: @JustJohn: Well the thing with accident commits is, that once its commited, that sensitive data is hard to remove from the repository, especially on distributed version system like git where multiple people have local copies. But even removing it from the main git repository will just break stuff for a lot of people cause every open pull request and branches will be broken who are based on a commit after that accidental commit (removing stuff from git means rewriting the whole git history and creating with new commit hashes)

Comment: @Tseng: Got no Git.